# Является ли правильной практикой, объединять несколько ссылок на объекты POJO классов в один класс, для удобного доступа к ним через последний

Tags: java, pojo, антипаттерн

Например:

```
public class A {
    // Какие-то переменные экземпляра и т.д.
}

public class B {
    // Какие-то переменные экземпляра и т.д.
}

public class C {
    // Какие-то переменные экземпляра и т.д.
}
```

И класс который объединяет все остальные:

```
public class All {
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    public All(A a, B b, C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    // Геттеры и сеттеры для получения доступа к переменным экземпляра.
}
```

Имеет ли такой подход место жить? Или все-таки лучше получать доступ к экземплярам классов по отдельности?

Comment: Из примеров кода неясно в чем заключается «удобный доступ через последний». Может расскажете почему неудобно использовать A, B и C по отдельности? Возможно в этом и кроется суть проблемы.

Comment: вы сейчас этим вопросом напомнили ребят, которые пишут на юнити (без обид, просто типичная проблема языков с низким порогом входа). они "заразились" такой болезнью, которую называют менеджер и искренне считают это паттерном. в менеджере есть ссылки на на объекты, а у менеджеров есть менджер, а у него менджер. такая матрешка. и для них это "очень удобно", потому что, всегда можно получит ссылку на любой класс. и все это, разумеется синглтоны, включая вложенные классы. они так прячут статику, за которую уже в открытую бьют ногами. и потом жалуются на утечку памяти)))

Comment: Удобность в том - что все находится в одном месте. По идее код должен получиться чище. И еще, возможность хранить объекты класса All вместе со ссылками в коллекциях (List например).

Comment: @Дмитрий Я понимаю, что матрешка из менеджеров - это очень плохо. В моем случае добаляется лишь один слой и нет статики. Да и со статикой слишком сильно баловаться не стоит).

Comment: это сейчас один. вышеназванные парни тоже не с 50 начинали)) он же один не потому, что больше быть не может. он один, потому что ваша бизнесс-логика на данном этапе тривиальна, как только она (логика) усложнится, все изменится))

Comment: @Дмитрий В общем вы не поддерживаете такую идею. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @RedEYE в общем нет. это не значит, что класс в принципе не может иметь полей типа другого класса (это вполне нормально).

Comment: Использование поля, которое ссылается на родительский объект является обычной практикой. Но нужно учитывать, что это может привести к зацикливанию алгоритмов, связанных с динамической обработкой полей классов через Reflection API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По структуре `All` ничем не отличается от обычного POJO:

```
class Employee {
     Person person;
     Department department;
     Manager manager;
     ...
}
```

Т.е. в структуре, как таковой, ничего сверхкриминального нет. Целесообразность же зависит от того как класс будет использоваться.

Имеет ли `All` логический смысл? Можно ли дать классу какое-то осмысленное имя? Наверняка есть какая-либо причина по которой `A`, `B` и `C` часто используются вместе.

Будут ли у `All` какие-либо обязанности? Если над «вложенными» объектами выполняются одни и те же действия, то возможно их стоит заключить в методы как раз в `All`.

В общем, если `All` улучшает код, то он имеет смысл, если нет — то нет. Дать более точный ответ не зная как и где классы используются нельзя. Паттерны проектирования не висят в воздухе, они очень тесно связаны с алгоритмами.